# Xmas Pudding put in microwave by mistake for 5 minutes

Tags: steaming

I put the wrong bowl in the microwave and cooked my raw xmas pudding mix for 4 mins. It was meant to be steamed for 8 hours tomorrow. It’s  now pale and semi cooked. What shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

Christmas puddings can be cooked in the microwave, so the best thing is to fully cook it immediately (either in the microwave or by steaming) and then reheat tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Chill it down as fast as possible, put in the fridge.

Steam it normally tomorrow.